# Magento 1.8.1 Review Forms / captcha: reviews not showing up in backend

Tags: forms, captcha, review, magento-1.8

I'm using Fontis recaptcha on  contact-form and Review-form. Until recently it works like a charm. After upgrading from 1.8 to 1.8.1 the contact-form / captcha is working fine but the review-form / captcha doesn't work properly. Filling review fields, captcha and sending looks fine. But I get no message that review is accepted and the review never shown up in backend. So it looks like it's lost in space.

Can someboyd help me because reviews are importing to the clients and me

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem. If you are using Fontis Rc V2.5 You need to amend 2 files...I've let Fontis know, so hopefully they will update the extension.

1) Update recaptcha.xml (design layout file), change:
From

< review_product_list>
< **block** name="product.review.form">
< block type="core/template" name="recaptcha.box" as="recaptcha_box" template="fontis/recaptcha/recaptcha.phtml"/>
        < /**block**>

To:
< review_product_list >
        <**reference** name="product.review.form">
            < block type="core/template" name="recaptcha.box" as="recaptcha_box" template="fontis/recaptcha/recaptcha.phtml"/>
        < /**reference**>

2) Update the form.phtml located in the fontis template design file and add under < form action="... > simply add
< ?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ? >

3) Flush cache and all should be working for product reviews. (Well is did for us)